# If $g \in C^{3}(0,1)$ and $g(0)=g(1)=g'(0)=0$, prove that there exists $\xi \in (0,1)$ such that $g(x) = g'''(\xi)x^2(x-1)/6$

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion

I saw a question as follow:

given a function $f \in C^{3}(0,1)$ and $f(0)=-1$, $f(1)=0$, $f^{\prime}(0)=0$, prove that for all $x \in (0,1)$, there exists $\xi \in (0,1)$ such that

$$f(x) = -1 + x^2 +\frac{x^2(x-1)}{3!}f^{\prime \prime \prime}(\xi)$$

Let $g(x) = f(x) +1 - x^2$, thus $g(0)=g(1)=g^{\prime}(0)=0$ and $g^{\prime \prime \prime}(x) = f^{\prime \prime \prime}(x)$. It simplifies this question I think.

However I did not solve it by using Taylor-expansion and Darboux theorem.

At the same time, I want to know if there is a more general conclusion as follow:

For a function $f \in C^{n+m}(a,b)$ (i.e, there exists $f^{\prime}(x), f^{\prime \prime}(x), \cdots, f^{(n+m)}(x)$ in $(a,b)$).

$$f^{(i)}(a)=0,~0 \leq i < n$$
and
$$f^{(j)}(b)=0,~0 \leq j < m$$

Prove that for every $x \in (a,b)$, there exists $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $$f(x) = \frac{(x-a)^{n}(x-b)^{m}}{(n+m)!}f^{(n+m)}(\xi )$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any fixed $x\in(0,1)$, construct fuction 
$$F(s)=g(s)-\frac{g(x)}{x^2(x-1)}s^2(s-1),\ s\in[0,1]$$
It is easy to konw: $F(0)=F(x)=F(1)=F'(0)=0.$
So Rolle Theorem implies there exists $s_1\in(0,x)$ and $s_2\in(x,1)$
such that $$F'(s_1)=F'(s_2)=0.$$ 
Combining $F'(0)=0$ by using Rolle Theorem again,
there exists $\eta_1\in(0,s_1)$ and $\eta_2\in(s_1,s_2)$
such that $F''(\eta_1)=F''(\eta_2)=0.$
In the end, Rolle Theorem implies there exists $\xi\in(\eta_1,\eta_2)$
such that $$F'''(\xi)=0$$ which proves you question!

The "More General Conclusion " is also ture,and can be done in the same way!